# what are the current best practices for key generation

Tags: openssl

What is the difference between these openssl commands:

- "openssl genrsa"
- "openssl genpkey"
- "openssl req -newkey rsa:bits [everything else]"

Which one should I be using when preparing a new CSR?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143442/what-are-ssh-keygen-best-practices)?  Maybe consider changing question title?

Answer (score 1):

The key generation code is the same in all three cases anyway. This is just a matter of *command-line interface*.

For most usages, I recommend generating the private key with `req` because then that's only one command line to generate the key *and* the certificate request. All other things being equal, less complexity makes for more security.