# How does OpenSSL generate a big prime number so fast?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, rsa

In order to generate a 2048 bit RSA key pair, you need to generate two big prime numbers with 1024 bits length. As far as I know, OpenSSL chooses a random 1024 bit number and starts looking for a prime number around it. How can OpenSSL check if the number is prime or not so quickly?

Answer (score 49):

**Testing for primality is much easier than performing integer factorization.**

There are several ways to test for primality, such as the deterministic [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and the probabilistic [Miller–Rabin primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test). OpenSSL uses [several tests](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/bn/bn_prime.c) to check for primality. First they subject the number to the deterministic checks, attempting division of the candidate against small primes, then a series of probabilistic Miller–Rabin primality tests. The vast majority of candidate primes are discarded with the very first primality test. Any candidates which pass them are subject to further rounds of testing, each of which increase the certainty that it is a prime.

This is possible at a high speed because verifying that an integer is a prime with an extremely low margin of error is significantly easier than factoring it, and because primes are not *that* uncommon (it is easy to find a large number of primes by incrementing a number and testing for primality). To test an integer *n*  where *n* = 2<sup>*s*</sup>*d* + 1 with *s* and *d* positive and *d* odd, the algorithm chooses a random [witness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(mathematics)) *a* in the range [2, *n* - 1) and checks if *a*<sup>*d*</sup> ≡ 1 (mod *n*) (the [Fermat test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)) and *a*<sup>2<sup>*r*</sup>*d*</sup> ≡ -1 (mod *n*) for some *r* in [0, *s*). If both of these congruence relations hold true, then *n* is probably prime.

Although it's often said that a composite number will survive a single Miller–Rabin test with no more than a 1/4 chance, the false positive rate for *generated* primes is actually significantly lower. A paper from 1993 [proved](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/PDF/paper88.pdf) that a *k*-bit composite will survive a single round of testing with no greater than a *k*<sup>2</sup>4<sup>2 - *√k*</sup> chance for any *k* ≥ 2. Even stronger bounds exist for larger numbers, with 2<sup>-75</sup> for *k* = 600! There are also a number of much slower ways to test if a number is prime with [complete certainty](https://cr.yp.to/primetests.html), such as [ECPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality), but for cryptographic purposes, multiple rounds of Miller–Rabin is *plenty*.

In some cases, OpenSSL does some other tests to look for a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime), so when prime *p* is found, it also checks if (*p* - 1) / 2 is prime. This is important for specific applications of primes such as Diffie–Hellman where safe primes prevent certain attacks, although it is not necessary for RSA because an algorithm called [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) negates the [supposed benefits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/47733/54184).

The pseudocode implementation of the test taken from Wikipedia is:

```
Input: n > 3, an odd integer to be tested for primality;
       k, a parameter that determines the accuracy of the test
Output: composite if n is composite, otherwise probably prime
```

```
write n − 1 as 2r·d with d odd by factoring powers of 2 from n − 1
WitnessLoop: repeat k times:
    pick random integer a in the range [2, n − 2]
    x ← ad mod n
    if x = 1 or x = n − 1 then
        continue WitnessLoop
    repeat r - 1 times:
        x ← x2 mod n
        if x = 1 then
            return composite
        if x = n − 1 then
            continue WitnessLoop
    return composite
return probably prime
```

See [this Crypto.SE answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1970/54184) on RSA key generation and the [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) standard, section 5.1.

Comment: I'm trying to think of how you would use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to find *large* prime numbers, based on the linked Wikipedia article, and I'm not sure how you would actually use it effectively for large primes. Do you have a better link describing usage for finding large primes? Or, are there other deterministic tests that are more-commonly used?

Comment: @EthanKaminski Might not be used by OpenSSL, but I know OpenSSH uses it, see `moduli(5)`. It looked like OpenSSL used it because the of the "fast test" in the source, but I just skimmed it. Though on second thought, `BN_is_prime_fasttest_ex()` seems to just do a trial division of a number of pre-computed small primes.

Comment: @EthanKaminski: The Sieve of Eratosthenes might be used to generate the small primes for the first test. It surely isn't used to generate every prime until 2**1024.

Comment: `BN_is_prime_fasttest_ex` can first try the fixed list of small primes, but this is skipped if the caller says so and `BN_generate_prime_ex` used for RSA does because `probable_prime` has already done the sieving using a faster incremental method; then fasttest does a loop `for(i=0;i<checks;i++) ... BN_pseudo_rand(check) ... witness(check,..,A1_odd,k,...) ...` where each call of `witness` does one M-R trial with random `check` and `A1_odd,k` the decomposition of candidate-1 to odd and power-of-two as you explained. But your wp quote lost the superscripting for 2^s a^d x^2 .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you, I hadn't noticed that. Corrected the pseudocode.

Comment: Does this mean, that even the final primes are not fully checked for being prima numbers, but are only very very unlikely to be composite numbers?

Comment: @allo Correct. The Rabin Miller tests do not prove primality, they just show that the chances that it is _not_ a prime are vanishingly small. Like, small enough that you can easily be just as likely to guess a 128-bit symmetric key on your first try.

Comment: You write: "(...) but for cryptographic purposes, being really, really sure is sufficient (...)". Why is the (very *very*) small probability good enough if algorithms are build on the assertion that an actual prime is used? Wouldn't weaken it?

Comment: @Jacco When the probability is as low as 2^-128, you really don't have to worry about it. After all, you're just as likely to guess a 128-bit key on the first try.

Comment: Beware naive attempts at randomized primality tests like Miller–Rabin tests.  It is critical that the witnesses be chosen unpredictably and independently; otherwise an adversary can [fool the test](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/749) into falsely reporting that maliciously chosen composites are prime.