# How secure is connecting to a machine behind a router with SSH tunnels using a 3rd machine that has static IP address?

Tags: ssh

I found the article that describes how to access a Linux machine behind a home router with SSH tunnels.
https://juliansimioni.com/blog/howto-access-a-linux-machine-behind-a-home-router-with-ssh-tunnels/

How safe is such setup? I'm not an expert, so not sure if there are any pitfalls.

My use case is almost the same as the authors:

- Ubuntu Desktop that I need to connect to. The desktop is behind a WiFi router. External IP is dynamic.
- My Linux laptop from which I need to connect.
- I need to set everything up once due to dynamic IP address.
- I can get a Linux VM in a cloud with a static IP address.

If I go with that solution, is it possible to use public keys instead of password authentication in such setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That proposal opens a reverse-tunneled port from the NAT'd system (the final destination SSH server on your LAN) to the world. It's clunky; if you want that sort of thing, just set up port forwarding from your router.

The "proper" SSH solution would be to accept SSH connections on your public-facing system (router) and use it as a jump host into your network. Then you're as secure as your router's SSH *plus* your NAT'd system's SSH (the port-forward and reverse-tunnel solutions have zero security for the router and rely solely on the security of your NAT'd system).

After you've set up ssh open to the world on your router (which, by the way, should *not* allow root to log into, or at least not without a key), you can connect like this:

```
ssh -J username@my-router me@lan-system
```

This will connect as `username` to the router, then immediately forward a connection to the lan system as user `me`. (Specifying a user is optional, it'll default to your local user name.) This is all performed from your local client's perspective, so if you're using SSH keys (which you requested—and you should), the private keys all live on your local system, *not* the jump box (the router).

This [SSH jump host guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host) has some good examples, including how to use your `~/.ssh/config` to make it automatic (so you'd type `ssh lan-system` instead).

#### To set up key-based authentication

On your local client `my-laptop`, [create a key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143442/what-are-ssh-keygen-best-practices/144044#144044) (make an RSA key if ed25519 is unsupported, see that link):

```
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 100
```

Make sure it has a password on it. We'll get to saving the password with `ssh-agent` later. This will create `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` (your private key) and `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`  (your public key) by default, which is fine. You can also use `-C "comment about your key"` if you want something other than the default `username@host`.

Now you can copy the public key to the jump box (`my-router`):

```
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ ssh username@my-router "mkdir -p .ssh; chmod 700 .ssh; cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys" <~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

This should be the last time you'll be prompted for your router user's password.

This runs three commands on the router. First, it ensures you have a `~/.ssh` directory. Then, it ensures its permissions are correct (700 is `drwx------`). Finally, it appends the input to your list of authorized keys. After that, we're piping the public key via standard input (think of this like passing a ball; you hand the ball to ssh and it instructs the remote system to hold onto it in that prescribed location).

You should now be able to log in with the key, but let's set up your SSH agent first.

There's a good chance you're already running an SSH agent, so let's just try it:

```
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Enter passphrase for /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519: [your typing will be invisible]
Identity added: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
me@my-laptop:/home/me$
```

If that worked, you're good to go. If not, you'll need to launch an agent:

```
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 1234567
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Enter passphrase for /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519: [your typing will be invisible]
Identity added: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
me@my-laptop:/home/me$
```

You should look into how to do this for your whole desktop environment rather than per-shell, but you could just add `` eval `ssh-agent -s` `` to your `~/.bashrc` if you're willing to deal with having to run `ssh-add` in each terminal you open rather than having it managed centrally.

You should now be able to run `ssh username@my-router` and log in automatically with your agent's unlocked key.

Let's connect to the NAT'd system `lan-system` now. This should look familiar:

```
me@my-laptop:/home/me$ ssh -J username@my-router me@lan-system "mkdir -p .ssh; chmod 700 .ssh; cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys" <~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

This will automatically jump through `my-router` and request your `me` password for `lan-system`, then it will install your key. After that, you can run `ssh -J username@my-router me@lan-system` and log in seamlessly with your agent.

Finally, you can shorten this command line by putting this stanza into your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host lan-system
  ProxyJump username@my-router
  UserName me
```

This will let you run `ssh lan-system` on its own. The `UserName` line is unnecessary if you have the same username. The same goes for the `username@` part of the `ProxyJump` line.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. One thing I didn't get is how to install OpenSSH to a wifi router. It likely has some Linux on it, but I'm not sure. I searched for that but couldn't find anything. Found only recommendations to set up port forwarding on the router side.

Comment: Port forwarding is fine, as I noted. Otherwise, for an embedded system like a router running a more usable OS like [OpenWRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt), I recommend [Dropbear SSH](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html).