# openssl: genrsa vs req -newkey private keys. What's the difference?

Tags: certificates, openssl, key-generation

I'm trying to understand the difference between generating a private key using `openssl genrsa` and adding `-newkey` to `req`.

I found a [2014 answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55868/what-are-the-current-best-practices-for-key-generation/55870#55870) saying the underlying code is the same, [one from 2015](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93494/160906) saying the encryption is different, and [a 2017 mailing list answer](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-August/006194.html) saying `genrsa` "creates keys in a legacy RSA algorithm-specific format." However, I don't see any reference to this in the docs for [genrsa](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-genrsa.html) nor for [req](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html).

Is there any substantial difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `openssl genrsa` in both OpenSSL 1.1.1f & 3.0.9 generates a 2048-bit RSA key, as well as the `openssl req -newkey rsa`. If you examine the resulting private keys with `openssl rsa -text` you will notice that there are the same key components of the same size.

The main difference seems to be that `openssl req -newkey rsa` protects the private key with a password by default, whereas `openssl genrsa` requires an extra parameter for that.

Comment: _In versions below 3.0.0_ `genrsa` writes 'traditional' (PKCS1) format; in 3.0.0 up it writes PKCS8. `req -newkey` writes PKCS8 since 1.0.0. `genrsa` defaults to unencrypted, but you can specify encryption with (almost) any cipher; `req -newkey` is encrypted unless either commandline option _or the config file_ says no, and if encrypted is always 3DES. If you don't specify the length (which you can and always could in either method) the default is 2048 since 1.0.2 for `genrsa` and 1.0.2g for `req -newkey`; before those it was less and sometimes differed between the two methods.